# Chess engine in python

Tags: engines, python, development, open-source

Are there any open-source chess engines that are written in primarily or fully in python? For example, Stockfish is written in primarily C++.

Answer (score 2):

There [are](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Category:Python), but none of them are top engines.

Comment: Which doesn't surprise since Python wasn't invented for speed, and speed is very critical. (Judging from my own experience with Python vs FORTRAN, "same" code, C++ might have a speed factor of 10 advantage.)